# Bash why quotes in while cycles make different behaviour?

Tags: bash

I wanted to read an input `$1` using parameters. I used this code:

```
while [ -n "$1" ]
do
   case $1 in
        -dt) do something;;
   esac
   shift
done
```

Why if I remove those quotes in the while instruction the script is stuck in a permanent loop? Quotes should let you evaluate a string making special characters like normal characters but I'm not inserting any special character in the input and anyway it has a different behavior with or without quotes

Comment: What is the argument you are passing?

Comment: something like -dt hello.. so I launch like ./Script.sh -dt hello

Comment: Had you run the script with the arguments you've shown, it will _not_ loop indefinitely. Explain your actual problem

Comment: the script that I wrote above is fine.. it has no problem. My question was regarding the quotes: as you can see in the very first line there are quotes, if you remove those quote the script will be stuck in an infinite loop. My question was: why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Without the quotes, when `$1` is empty, `[ -n $1 ]` will become `[ -n ]` which means `[ -n "-n" ]` which is TRUE.

According to bash [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html):

> `test` and `[` evaluate conditional expressions using a set of rules
>    based on the number of arguments.
>
> ```
> 0 arguments
>     The expression is false.
> 1 argument
>     The expression is true if and only if the argument is not null.
> [...]
> ```

Comment: but OP claims they pass `-dt hello` as arguments, so there is no reason for `$1` to be empty

Comment: there is no `break`?

Comment: There is _no_ `break` construct for `case` statements in `bash`. Only `;;`

Comment: @Inian The OP shifts the arguments after each iteration, so eventually $1 becomes empty.

Comment: @pynexj why [ -n ] means [ -n "-n" ]? I'm sorry I have some lacking about this

Comment: @Inian - everytime after the case block it will shift so eventually $1 will be empty.

Comment: @p.l. -- `The expression is true if and only if the argument is not null` so logically `[ "something" ]` just means `[ -n "something" ]` and so `[ -n ]` logically means `[ -n -n ]`.

Comment: `[` uses the *number* of arguments it receives to decide how to interpret them. When it gets one argument (ignoring the mandatory final `]` argument), it simply treats it as a string that is either empty or non-empty; `[ foo ]` has the same *meaning* as the two argument command `[ -n foo ]`.